# VS Code 1.19.3 debugging .net core 2 and always meet "Only 64-bit processes can be debugged"

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've installed both x86 & x64 sdk of **.net core 2.0** on my laptop (win 7 sp1 x64). I don't know why the vs code (1.19.3 & x64 & official [c# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp)) always choose the x86 runtime auto to build my console and always meet error and popup message: "**Only 64-bit processes can be debugged.**".

Then I tried:

1. I read the question of [.NET Core debugging with VS Code - “Only 64-bit processes can be debugged”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343721/net-core-debugging-with-vs-code-only-64-bit-processes-can-be-debugged). And seems not working for me at all followed the answer to change the json file and csproj file.
2. I've tried simple console project by running **"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet" new console**. The error message is there while debugging.
3. Also, I've tried force to point to x64 runtime to build by modifying the file **.vscode\tasks.json**:

   {

   ```
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
       {
           "taskName": "build",
           "command": "dotnet", --> change to "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
           "type": "process",
           "args": [
               "build",
               "${workspaceFolder}/VSDebugCoreTest.csproj"
           ],
           "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
       }
   ]
   ```

   }

The error message is still there "Only 64-bit processes can be debugged.".

I've x64 vscode, I've x64 sdk & runtime, I've create & compile with x64 version of sdk, and from the internal terminal show me the compiled succeeded.

**Anyone know why and how to bypass this error and able to debugging?** (please do NOT tell me to install VS, it's huge for me.)

Answer (score 11):

I faced similar issue trying to debug azure function in VSCode. The problem was in **azure-functions-core-tools** installed through chocolatey. Currently it is installing x86 version of tools. Steps I made to solve the problem:

1. run `choco uninstall azure-functions-core-tools`
2. download nupkg file from [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/azure-functions-core-tools)
3. edit *tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1* script (change x86 to x64 in a url)
4. run `choco install azure-functions-core-tools -source . --ignore-checksums` in a folder where edited nupkg file is
5. have fun debugging your functions in VSCode

Comment: Good find! I was having exactly the same issue after installing the functions core tools through chocolatey. Btw, installing them from npm downloads the correct version.

Comment: For people like me that wonder how to find/edit chocolateyinstall.ps1, you can modify it with nuget package explorer https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer

Comment: i was able to install it by passing the x64 parameter directly to the choco install command 
`choco install azure-functions-core-tools --params "'/x64:true'"`

Answer (score 5):

After about one day's investigation, I got the real reason and the solution. Thanks for anyone who read my question. (self ask self answer)

Reason:

1. I installed x86 .net core sdk beside x64 one. Then system environment variable "path" contains both **C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet** and **C:\Program Files\dotnet**;
2. The debugger of .net core in visual studio code now is only support x64 version. Even if I force use x64 to build, the debugger recognize **dotnet.exe** in path and implicitly use x86 dotnet.exe to **run** a x64 program;

That's why I always got the error message: "Only 64-bit processes can be debugged."

My solution is quite easy:

1. remove **C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet** from path;

or

2. uninstall x86 .net sdk thoroughly.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me, as I only have the x64 version installed :(

Comment: install only x64 version of vscode, also install only x64 version of .net core. it may bypass the issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Environment variables
2. Select Edit for Path system variable
3. Move C:\Program Files\dotnet\ entry up over C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
4. Click OK
5. Close and start VS Code again.

Comment: This helped me, this was as simple as it comes. Thank you.